# Ubuntu 18.04 recording problem: cannot record any audio

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, pavucontrol

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to record an audio. Though an audio file is being created, but it doesn't have any sound.

I am using front panel port.

Comment: Run pavucontrol > input devices. See if the input is enabled and unmuted.

Comment: yes, I have used this command. It is enabled and unmuted

Answer (score 0):

The recorded files in Ubuntu 18.04 are by default hidden.
Right click on one of .wav files and uncheck hidden. Try again. It will work possibly!